# trying to convert aspx to dnn module in dnn 6.2

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I was reading this http://alainrivas.blogspot.com/2008/08/dnn-dotnetnuke-module-development-in-10.html and was wondering if the rules still applied for 6.2. If so there are a couple of holes in this plan.

1. what I have already changed is the conversion of the vb code to cs
2. there is no import module definition option. Under extensions all that is listed for me are the install extension wizard, create new extension and create new module. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are refactoring to use as a module there is no real reason to convert code unless you like one or the other. Once the pages are converted to ascx controls it should be just like setting up any other module (and then extensive testing.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of creating the modules. 
For your case (conversion of the existing code), I think the most simple is to create a *.dnn file and list your module definition in there and then import it using the install extension wizard. (it will give you the choice of how to import the module)